# jQuery error on .after()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple piece of jQuery code (jQuery 1.7.1). Though the error below shows up, and the code isn't executed.

> Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong.

The code that causes this error is as follows:

```
counter = 0;
jQuery('h3').each(function(){
    counter += 1;
    div = '<div class="' + counter + '"></div>';
    jQuery(this).after(div);
    jQuery(this).nextUntil('h3').appendTo('div.' + counter);
});
```

For some reason, the `jQuery(this).after(div);` causes a problem. It has something to do with the class I am adding to the div (specifically the class, not the variable I set as class). At first I used append instead of after, but that didn't give the desired effect. However, append didn't give an error.

Can anyone clarify why I am not allowed to add a class in the after function, and if possible, give me a good alternative to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to insert the div into itself. Indeed, `jQuery(this).after(div)` results in :

```
<h3></h3>
<div class="1"></div>
<h3></h3>
```

So then, `jQuery(this).nextUntil('h3')` includes the div itself. Here is how to avoid this situation :

```
jQuery(this).nextUntil('h3')
    .not('div.' + counter)
    .appendTo('div.' + counter);
```

This has nothing to do with your question, but I wonder if a CSS class beginning with a number is valid or not : https://stackoverflow.com/a/449000/1636522.

Comment: You are right (in both the CSS class and the div inserting into itself). It gave me a push in the right direction. Though you didn't really give me a working solution, you did help me solve this problem myself. So I'll accept this answer for that.

Comment: It can [Class names with numbers], only in HTML5 though.

Comment: @SanderKoedood Thanks :) I've added a solution.

Comment: @MackieeE Link broken :/

Comment: Oh, nice. The exact same solution as I came up with. @MackieeE, I think class names with numbers are still not recommendable, since you'd need to escape the first character to use it.

Comment: @wared It wasn't a link! but here is one =) http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute "*IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation*" and you're right sanderKoedood I'd never actively say numbers as class names will never really be recommended, but it is doable and thus won't throw errors.